# how we can query a cloud storage using external table in node js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I want to query the cloud storage using the external table concept in nodejs. I was able to see code in python for obtaining the same functionality. But want to do the same logic in nodejs. So, is it possible.

Comment: It's the same concept  - create an external table definition that points to GCS and query the table as you would any other using SQL from your Node application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current official support for this using Node.JS. Meaning, even if you manage to achieve this, it would just be a temporary non-supported workaround. Which is why I filed a Feature Request on the Public Issue Tracker that you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/121311494).

I recommend you to star the FR, for easy visibility and access for viewing the status updates. The BigQuery team might ask questions there too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21742959)

Comment: @HarshaB This provides an answer indeed. There's no current support for this in Node.JS, and I took the necessary steps to help community, and solve this question(s) in the future, which from my point of view, is useful. All current solutions, would just be temporary non-supported workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to google console and create new table based on cloud storage
[image: New Table]
2) Use Javascript code as defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) which you can use in your node.js code

This is sample code

```
/**
     *
     * @param request: Store BQ request configuration
     * @param params: Store workflow data params
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    static bigQueryInsertPromise2(request, params) {
        return new Promise(resolved => {
            bigQuery.jobs.insert(request, request, (err, results) => {
                resolved([err, results ? results.data : null])
            })
        }).then((args) => {
            let [err, results] = args
            //Handle results in status processing
            return this.getResultByJobId(err, results, params).then(args => {
                let [err, jobResults] = args
                if (err) {
                    if (err.message) {
                        throw [err.message, null]
                    } else {
                        console.log(`Error from Google: ${err.errors}`)
                        throw [err, null]
                    }
                }
                jobResults.configuration = results.configuration
                return [null, jobResults]
            })
        }).then(args => {
            let [err, jobResults] = args
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                throw [err, null]
            }

            return args
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired functionality is achieved using the external data configuration, where we can provide the necessary details for setting up the connection with the file. Once done we can query the desired location from BQ using node.js